# What roll must be made to satisfy the Prey Exclusion flaw?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

**Prey Exclusion**, V20 Core Rulebook page 485 (emphasis mine):

> You refuse to hunt a certain class of prey. You might refuse to feed on drug dealers, policemen, accountants, or rich people — if you accidentally feed upon such an individual, you automatically frenzy ***and must make a roll to prevent Humanity or Path loss (difficulty 7).***

To what type of roll does this passage refer? A standard degeneration roll using the Conscience/Conviction trait? A roll to resist frenzy using the Self-Control trait? A roll using the character's Humanity/Path trait? A roll using the character's Willpower trait?

Furthermore, can a character spend a point of Willpower to get an automatic success on this roll? The rule for standard degeneration rolls is no, but standard degeneration rolls are set against a difficulty of 8 by default (instead of 7, as **Prey Exclusion** says) and are prompted by committing a sin as defined by your path according to the section on Morality (again, emphasis mine):

> The system is simple: Whenever a character takes an action that the Storyteller decides is morally questionable, the character may suffer degeneration -- a permanent loss of Humanity. ***If degeneration is a possibility, the player whose character commits the act should make a Conscience roll for that character. The difficulty is 8 -- reprehensible acts are hard to justify -- though the Storyteller may modify this. Willpower may not be spent for an automatic success on this roll -- all the ego in the world won't protect a character from guilt.***

I believe the above text can be reasonably interpreted two different ways; either you can't use Willpower to guarantee success on a degeneration roll prompted by committing a sin according to your own moral compass (which would include self-restriction via flaws like **Prey Exclusion** in addition to sins defined by your path), or you can't use Willpower to guarantee success on a degeneration roll prompted by committing a sin as defined by your path.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The roll is a *standard degeneration roll* (a roll without the ability to spend willpower for a success), with a modified difficulty.  Flaws often change the details of a standard roll to fit the context of the situation, and this is no different.  You are excluding prey on your own; the moral basis of your path does not dictate that you exclude prey.  It is not on the hierarchy of sins.